# best way for select row mysql

Tags: mysql, database, row, mysql5

Which of the following notations is better?

```
SELECT id,name,data FROM table WHERE id = X
```

OR

```
SELECT id,name,data FROM table WHERE id = X LIMIT 1
```

I think it should not have "LIMIT".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a unique constraint on `id` then they will be exactly the same.

If there isn't a unique constraint (which I would find highly surprising on a column called `id`) then which is better depends on what you want to do:

- If you want to find **all rows** matching the condition, don't use `LIMIT`.
- If you want to find **any row** matching the condition (and you don't care which), use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: The sentence "limit" uses more resources in this query. Do you think the same?

Comment: @OlafErlandsen: Why does using LIMIT use more resources? Do you have a citation for that?

Comment: I'm not sure.
I think it has more code to interpret. Now, although the documentation says: "LIMIT" help bring a specific range of results.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen: That's a micro-optimization at best (if there is a measurable difference at all). If the difference is actually a concern for you then it's because you're firing off thousands of select statements, each fetching one row, in rapid succession. If you're doing that, the chances are you are *doing it wrong*. Fetch more data per query. Instead of 1000 queries that each fetch one row, change it to one query that fetches 1000 rows all at once. It will be *much* faster.

Answer (score 1):

Always use LIMIT with select statement even if you are fetching 1 record because it will speed up your query. So use :

```
SELECT id,name,data FROM table WHERE id = X LIMIT 1
```

For example :
If there are 1000 records in your table than if you using

```
SELECT id,name,data FROM table WHERE id = X
```

than it will traverse through 1000 records even if finds that id 
But if you using LIMIT like this

```
SELECT id,name,data FROM table WHERE id = X LIMIT 1
```

than it will stop executing when finds first record.

Comment: This answer only applies when there is no unique index. When there is a unique index (and if the column is called `id` then it probably does - or should - have a unique index) both queries will most likely use the index.